# How do I keep compiled code libraries up-to-date across multiple web sites using version control?

Tags: asp.net, .net, version-control, tfs, versioning

Currently, we have a long list of various websites throughout our company's intranet. Most are inside a firewall and require an Active Directory account to access. One of our problems, as of late, has been the increase in the number of websites and the addition of a common code library that stores our database access classes, common helper functions, serialization methods, etc. The goal is to use that framework across all websites throughout the company.

Currently, we have upgraded the in-house data entry application with these changes consistently. It is up-to-date. The problem, however, is maintaining all of the other websites. Is there a best practice or way in which I find out versions on each website and upgrade accordingly? Can I have a centralized place where I keep these DLLs and sites reference them? What's the best way to go about finding out what versions are on these websites without having to go through each and every single website, find out the version, and upgrade after every change?

Keep in mind, we run the newest TFS and are a .NET development team.

Comment: If you create a Windows Class Library project (and an additional installation project) shift all your code into it that's shared you can then install it directly into the GAC on each webserver. That way you can ensure exactly the same code is running on all websites on each server. When you need to update you can then update the shared code base and then reinstall on the servers and everything is nicely in sync.

Comment: How do you deploy/update the sites now?  Manually?

Comment: Yes, we update manually, and we have had issues in which some sites are way out of date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At my job we have a similar setup to you, lots of internal applications that use common libraries, and I have spent the best part of a year sorting this all out.

The first thing to note is that nothing you mentioned really has anything to do with TFS, but is really a symptom of the way your applications, and their components, are packaged and deployed.

Here are some ideas to get you started:

## Setup automated/continuous builds

This is the first thing you need to do. Use the build facility in TFS if you must, or make the investment into something like TeamCity (which is great). Evaluate everything. Find something which you love and that everyone else can live with. The reason why you need to find something you love is because you will ultimately be responsible for it.

The reason why setting up automated builds is so important is because that's your jumping off point to solve the rest of your issues.

## Setup automated deployment

Every deployable artifact should now be being built by your build server. No more manual deployment. No more deployment from workstations. No more visual studio Publish feature. It's hard to step away from this, but it's worth it.

If you have lots of web projects then look into either using web deploy which can be easily automated using either msbuild/powershell or go fancy and try something like octopus deploy.

## Package common components using nuget

By now your common code should have its own automated builds, but how do you automatically deploy a common component? Package it up into nuget and either put it on a share for consumption or host it in a nuget server (TeamCity has one built in). A good build server can automatically update your nuget packages for you (if you always need to be on the latest version), and you can inspect which version you are referencing by checking your `packages.config`.

---

I know this is a lot to take in, but it is in its essence the fundamentals of moving towards  continuous delivery (http://continuousdelivery.com/).

Please beware that getting this right will take you a long time, but that the process is incremental and you can evolve it over time. However, the longer you wait the harder it will be. Don't feel like you need to upgrade all your projects at the same time, you don't. Just the ones that are causing the most pain.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, automated builds are a work in progress. I'm at the mercy of higher powers in making that decision. Fortunately, we are moving toward that model. Nuget is a solid suggestion though when we get there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to step outside the space of a specific solution for your problem and address the underlying desire you have to consolidate your workload.
Be aware that any patching/upgrading scenario will have costs that you must address - there is no magic pill.
Particularly, what you want to achieve will typically incur either a build/deploy overhead (as jonnii has outlined), or a runtime overhead (in validating the new versions to ensure everything works as expected).

In your case, because you have already built your products, I expect you will go the build/deploy  route.

Just remember that even with binary equivalence (everything compiles, and unit tests pass), there is still the risk that the application will behave somehow differently after an upgrade, so you will not be able to avoid at least some rudimentary testing across all of your applications (the GAC approach is particularly vulnerable to this risk).

You *might* find it easier to accept that just because you have built a new version of a binary, doesn't mean that it should be rolled out to all web applications, even ones that are already functioning correctly (if something ain't broke...).

If that is acceptable, then you will reduce your workload by only incurring resource expense on testing applications that actually *need* to be touched.